# VB.NET and Excel table formatting

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010

I wrote a small program in VB.NET to export data from DataGrid to Excel and it works perfectly. My manager now wants me to display the data in a presentable format. How should I go about it. I recorded a macro but was unable to apply that in vb.net. Is there any good tutorial which covers this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording Macros was a good start :) You can either show what you recorded and then I can take you through it or if you want you can have a look at this link

**Topic: VB.NET and Excel**

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/

See Point 8 "***Creating/Formatting a Table***"

BTW which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm using Excel 2010 and VB.NET 2010. I'm going thru your link.

Comment: @user1140588: Then that link will definitely help you :)

Comment: Simply Awesome!!!! It works. You made my day!!! BTW is that your blog? I found some other interesting stuff that I can do in Excel from vb.net like creating charts from the exported data. My Manager is definitely going to be very pleased with me. All thanks to you.

Comment: @user1140588: Glad to be of help :) Yes that is my blog.